# How does one Iterate through the elements of an Extendible Hashing structure (Set, specifically)

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, c++17

I have written an implementation of an Extendible Hashing Set in C++. I've used Arrays to achieve it and everything seems to be fine working fine. The bucket structure is simple

```
struct bucket {
    element *block = new element[N];
    size_t lDepth{0};
    ~element(){...}
};
```

For the container I'm using a `bucket** container;`

Splitting and expansion work well. I only can't figure out a meaningful way to iterate through the elements in my Iterator class with just the array. Is it possible to do so with just the `container` array or must I have a second array, where everything is properly arranged?.

Edit: Keys are distinguished by the "less?" significant bits.

Comment: I think you should keep a list of the non-empty buckets.

Comment: Its a hash table. Consequently, don't expect ordering. Your iterator should retain a bucket id and an offset (and obviously a reference to the hash table itself). incrementing the iterator should advance the offset, and if the end-of-bucket is reached, advanced the bucket-id.

Comment: Thank you both! That seems to be fine!